# Admob not showing up until phone is locked

Tags: android, java-native-interface, admob, cocos2d-x

I've implemented admob for my app using recent version of google play services. But it only appears after I perform lock and unlock my phone with application running.

```
AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
mAdView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();

        mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

PS:
I've called above piece of code from c++ code of cocos2d-x using JNI.

```
CCAdView* ad = CCAdView::create(kCCAdSizeSmartBanner, "ID");
 ad->setAlignment(kCCHorizontalAlignmentCenter, kCCVerticalAlignmentBottom);
 addChild(ad,3);
 ad->setVisible(true);
 ad->loadAd();
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what have you set your refresh time to?

Comment: I've not set any  refresh rate. Should that be problem? because once I lock and again unlock my phone it works.

Comment: Where is the above c++ code being called from?

Comment: From a class which is extended from Cococs2d-x CCLayer and is Child of CCScene.

Comment: What am I trying to ask/find out, is if this code is only being called when the app is resumed?  Is this code in the onCreate?

Comment: I've followed this : http://rastergrid.com/blog/2013/03/admob-extension-for-cocos2d-x-android/ 
tutorial line-by-line.

Comment: Better to place a comment on that blog site then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem too. And it seems that someone finally found a solution:

[AdMob won't show the banner until refresh or sign in to google plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408178/admob-wont-show-the-banner-until-refresh-or-sign-in-to-google-plus)