# Mobile advertise is not showed in android apps (AdMob)

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I am trying to show advertise in android app . For thi purpose I am trying to follow instructions given in this link .[Integrating AdMob in your Android App and make money](http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/integrating-admob-in-your-android-app-and-make-money/)

All instruction is done by me completely . But the add is not showed . Here is my android layout xml file .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7797575286962729/1058368497"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code of mainactivity is given in the following .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

At the last my menifest file is given in the following .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <activity 
             android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But the add is not showing . Here is a point , I am testing this app in eclipse emulator . Does this create a problem ? Please help me .

Comment: Change width to match_parent and give height to fix in dp like 50dp.

Comment: have you tried as per the google's official doc https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

     <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/addID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this in your code.Its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
  AdView addView = (AdView)finnViewById(R.id. adView);
    adMobView.setEnabled(true);
    adMobView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Try this. If not check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408178/admob-wont-show-the-banner-until-refresh-or-sign-in-to-google-plus)